# How to plot 3d data with python?(not just plot a surface)

Tags: python, matplotlib

For example, I have a data `x` with shape `(100,100,100)`

I use

```
xs = np.linspace(1,100,100)
ys = np.linspace(1,100,100)
zs = np.linspace(1,100,100)
xs, ys, zs = np.meshgrid(xs, ys, zs)
ax = plt.gca(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(xs,ys,zs,'o',c=x,alpha=0.1,cmap='Reds')
```

to plot this

[image]

And, I want to add more information like this from [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/contourf3d_2.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-contourf3d-2-py)
[image]

but replace

```
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-100, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=-40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
```

with

```
plt.pcolor(x.max(axis=0),cmap='Reds')
plt.pcolor(x.max(axis=1),cmap='Reds')
plt.pcolor(x.max(axis=2),cmap='Reds')
```

Comment: The documentation picture shows a function `f: [-30,30] x [-30,30] -> [-100, 100]`, i.e. a mapping of 2D space into 1D. The data you have is rather `f: [1,100] x [1,100] x [1,100] -> R`, i.e. a mapping of 3D space to 1D. So it's not clear how that should look like

Comment: I just try to use the documentation picture to explain how I want my picture looks like. It's not about the function in the documentation. There are four parts in the documentation picture, one 3D surface and three 2D figures. I want to plot `plt.pcolor(x.max(axis=0),cmap='Reds')` at the position of the three 2D figures. Sorry for my poor English.